# How to give input using speech recognition in a element in python

Tags: python, string, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyttsx3
import string
import random
#Text To Speech
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
#print(voices)
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 145) #you can replace it to incease or decrease dound speed default(200)
def speak(audio):  #here audio is var which contain text
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
#now convert audio to text
def takecom():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listning....")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognising....") 
        text = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(text)
    except Exception:      
        speak("error...")
        print("Network connection error") 
        return "none"
    return text
#for main function                               
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takecom().lower()
        if 'create password' in query or 'c' in query :
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                s1 = string.ascii_lowercase
                s2 = string.ascii_uppercase
                s3 = string.digits
                s4 = string.punctuation
                speak('what do you want to keep the length of the password type here')
                plen =int(input('what is the length of the password'))  #p
                s=[]
                s.extend(list(s1))
                s.extend(list(s2))
                s.extend(list(s3))
                s.extend(list(s4))
                print("Your password is:")
                print("".join(random.sample(s,plen)))
                speak("".join(random.sample(s,plen)))
        elif query == 'none':
            continue 
        elif 'exit' in query or 'abort' in query or 'stop' in query or 'bye' in query or 'quit' in query:
            ex_exit = 'ok byy'
            speak(ex_exit)
            exit()
```

When i run this code every thing work fine but it ask to write the length of the password and when i write to length in it then the code proceed but i don't want to write anything in it is there any way so that i can give a voice input in the function plen  (#p)  to do the program work with the help of voice command.
I am using python 3.8

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We need to you to minimize your supporting code, show your attempt, and display the desired and actual operation of that attempt.
Use complete sentences and clear references, rather than undefined pronouns and generic nouns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh god finally i got answer of my question by my own.
let's see the answer
In the line `plen =int(input('what is the length of the password'))  #p`
we need to change this code to `plen =int(takecom())` show that the word which we will speak will get directly converted into input in it and the code will work properly with voice command.

Here is the final code

```
import speech_recognition as sr 
import pyttsx3
import string
import random
#Text To Speech
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
#print(voices)
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[0].id)
engine.setProperty('rate', 145) #you can replace it to incease or decrease dound speed default(200)
def speak(audio):  #here audio is var which contain text
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
#now convert audio to text
def takecom():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listning....")
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        print("Recognising....") 
        text = r.recognize_google(audio,language='en-in')
        print(text)
    except Exception:      
        speak("error...")
        print("Network connection error") 
        return "none"
    return text
#for main function                               
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takecom().lower()
        if 'create password' in query or 'c' in query :
            if __name__ == "__main__":
                s1 = string.ascii_lowercase
                s2 = string.ascii_uppercase
                s3 = string.digits
                s4 = string.punctuation
                speak('what do you want to keep the length of the password type here')
                plen =int(takecom())  #p
                s=[]
                s.extend(list(s1))
                s.extend(list(s2))
                s.extend(list(s3))
                s.extend(list(s4))
                print("Your password is:")
                print("".join(random.sample(s,plen)))
                speak("".join(random.sample(s,plen)))
        elif query == 'none':
            continue 
        elif 'exit' in query or 'abort' in query or 'stop' in query or 'bye' in query or 'quit' in query:
            ex_exit = 'ok byy'
            speak(ex_exit)
            exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

just change ↓

```
plen =int(input('what is the length of the password'))  #p
```

to ↓

```
plen =int(takecom())  #p
```